# Ui.Router carrega/importa arquivos JS, mas botões perdem funcionalidade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-router

O template **SmartAdmin** usa **lazyScript** para importar os arquivos de JS, ele funciona, importa tudo certo, porem quando faço a navegação entre as páginas os botões de Ui, param de funcionar.

```
angular.module('app.analytics', ['ui.router'])
        .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

          $stateProvider
             .state('app.equipmentManagement', {
            url: '/gestao-de-equipamento',
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/equipmentManagementAnalytics.html'
                }
            },
            data:{
                title: 'Analytics'
            },
            resolve: {
                scripts: function(lazyScript){
                    return lazyScript.register([
                        'build/vendor.graphs.js',
                        'build/vendor.ui.js'
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.correlationAnalytics', {
            url: '/correlacao',
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/correlationAnalytics.html'
                }
            },
            data:{
                title: 'Analytics'
            },
            resolve: {
                scripts: function(lazyScript){
                    return lazyScript.register([
                        'build/vendor.graphs.js',
                        'build/vendor.ui.js'
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.eventFrame', {
            url: '/event-manager',
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/eventManager.html'
                }
            },
            data:{
                title: 'Event Manager'
            },
            resolve: {
                scripts: function(lazyScript){
                    return lazyScript.register([
                        'build/vendor.graphs.js',
                        'build/vendor.ui.js'
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O *template* não reconhece os *widgets*, por causa que a diretiva `data-widget-grid` não pode conter ela mesma em outra `div`.

Resolvi apenas removendo a diretiva `data-widget-grid` dos filhos.